# Is an SSL required for socket.io and HTML5 geolocation

Tags: html, sockets, ssl

I am trying to add multiplayer/chat and geolocation abilities to my website so far I have failed at both. I am convinced I need some sort of SSL at this point if only to allow me to bypass the socket.io/Chrome API issue i'm having. I am not interested in ecommerce or anything I consider crucial at this point. I have ipage and they offer a $39 SSL but I have seen as low as free to about $7. Any reason I should not get a cheap or free one? Thanks.

Comment: i found 5$ ssl -https://www.ssls.com/ssl-certificates/comodo-positivessl . I suggest you to use always ssl . With ssl you can access camera , websockets etc...

Comment: After purchasing 3 years ipage decides to make it clear they do not support 3rd party ssl.

Comment: For me best way is 5$ VPS (like digital ocean) .Then you can access with terminal prompt and setup anything you want. No restriction at all. You can use more than one server tehnology like php vs node.js , start video signal servers , io sockets . I use long time ago hpage free hosting they have great control panel .VPN services also give you auto script for CMS all of kind. You will need to choose easy access or full support custom setup.